# User configuration form for Google App Script program

Tags: google-apps-script, clasp

I have a headless google app script which performs some Drive operation on a timer.

I would like to publish it for distribution. But in order to do that, I need to expose some configuration values. What is the best way to do that?

I know I can fetch/store the values in UserProperties but how can I get the values from the user? Do I need to create a web app with a user interface for this?

Comment: In order to correctly understand your situation, can I ask you about the details of `I have a headless google app script which performs some Drive operation on a timer.`? For example, it's a flow when a user tries to use your application for the first time. I guessed that at that time, you might want to have given the specific values depending on the user. But, if I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: My script monitors a folder for uploaded files. It processes them, then puts the processed files in another folder. I would like people who install the script to be able to choose which folder to monitor, and which folder to output the results too.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I would like people who install the script to be able to choose which folder to monitor, and which folder to output the results too.`, in your current situation, how do you process this?

Comment: Currently I just have it hard coded.